# Diameter of the intersection of a nested family of sets is the limit of diameters?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, compactness

The following question popped up while thinking about Cantor's intersection theorem.

Consider a metric space $X$ so that we may talk of the diameters $\delta(A)$'s of its subsets $A$'s. Let $A_1\supseteq A_2\supseteq\cdots$ be a nested sequence of subsets of $X$ with $A_1$ bounded (that is, $\delta(A_1) < +\infty$). Then, can we say that $\delta(\cap_i A_i) = \lim_i\delta(A_i)$ (as intuition so loudly screams)?

The answer is affirmative if $A_i$'s are all compact (as shown by Brian M. Scott [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/198967/673223)). Cantor's intersection theorem says that this is true if $A_i$'s are closed with diameters going to zero. But can nothing more be said in general? Counterexamples are welcome.

Comment: You could have empty intersection of closed subsets of unit diameter.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Example?

Comment: Think about a basis of pairwise orthogonal vectors (of the same norm $1/\sqrt{2}$) in an infinite dimensional separable Hilbert space.

Comment: @MoisheKohan What are the subsets $A_i$'s here?

Comment: Just think for 5 minutes about it.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Still not able to go anywhere... :')

Comment: OK, $A_1=\{e_i: i\ge 1\}$, is the basis itself; $A_2=\{e_i: i\ge 2\}$. Can you continue the sequence?

Comment: @MoisheKohan Ooof! Thanks for bearing with my ignorance. If you post this as an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: A bit later....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A_1=\{e_i: i\ge 1\}$ be a countable orthonormal basis of an infinite-dimensional Hilbert space. Take $A_n:=\{e_i: i\ge n\}$. Then all these sets have the same diameter $\sqrt 2$ while their intersection is empty and hence has zero diameter.